# aws codedeploy git revision during deploy

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am running some test with AWS CodeDeploy service and managed to deploy my app from github, so far so good.

But now I need to git revision that is deployed in the AfterInstall hook. Is there a way to get the git revision?

Already looked in the deployment-archive dir but it looks like the agent is doing a git export since there is no .git directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the specific revision deployed, you'll have to pull the deployment details from CodeDeploy as it's not currently exposed to hook scripts.

1. Use the DEPLOYMENT_ID environment variable (set by the host agent) to get the deployment id.
2. Call [GetDeployment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_GetDeployment.html) with the deployment id.
3. In the response structure get the GitHub commit id from Revision -> GitHubLocation -> CommitID

Comment: thanks, this works. Hoped that there would be an environment var like $GIT_COMMIT_ID but this works as well

Comment: Calling `GetDeployment` from command-line should be possible, too: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/get-deployment.html

Answer (score -1):

If you login to the aws console, then go to deployment, so you can choose the the which revision do you want to deploy