# GitHub Environment Variables for AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I would like to access `GitHub.CommitMessage` during `AWS CodeDeploy` (as a part of AWS CodePipeline) phase in my `EC2 Instance`.

Additional details:

- private repo inside organization

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already answered how to get the git commit Id . basically,

#### get deployment  id

get the deployment id from `DEPLOYMENT_ID` environment variable

#### get commit id

make an api call to `GetDeployment` api end point with the deployment id to get the commit details

#### get commit message

now to get the commit message, github has a get commit api end point. This step requires a github access token

> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:ref

reference:
[aws codedeploy git revision during deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605439/aws-codedeploy-git-revision-during-deploy)

Comment: what about private repos inside organization? Is CodeDeploy authorized to do so?

Comment: access token is needed to fetch private repo details

Comment: have you found a way, i didn't a get a chance to look at it yet

Comment: Yes I did. I'm going to store github personal access tooken on EC2 and copy whole repository.

Comment: glad to be of help